# Scrapy not accepting japanese characters in spider

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Here is a part of the source code of the website i am trying to scrape.

```
<th>会社名</th>
<td colspan="2">
    <p class="realtorName">
        <ruby>株式会社エリア・エステート　川崎店</ruby>
    </p>
</td>
```

And this is just a test spider to see if scrapy is fetching any data

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["homes.co.jp"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.homes.co.jp/realtor/mid-122457hNYEJwIO7kDs/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            'FAX':response.xpath('//*[@id="anchor_realtorOutline"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/th[contains(text(), "FAX")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract(),
            'Company_Name':response.xpath('//*[@id="anchor_realtorOutline"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/th[contains(text(), "会社名")]/following-sibling::td/p[1]/ruby/text()').extract(),
            'TEl':response.xpath('//*[@id="anchor_realtorOutline"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/th[contains(text(), "TEL")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract(),



            }
```

The 'TEL' and 'FAX' fields would return data but scrapy throws an error for the field 'Company_Name'

Error:

```
All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters.
```

What i wanted to do was match that string in Japanese and obtain the text from the sibling tag as mentioned in the above source code.

And the strange fact is that it ran yesterday and scraped data. Now it's returning errors.

Do i need to do something to include the Japanese characterset?

Comment: As per Umair's code, That is converting the whole xpath to the scripts Unicode .
i.e. appending `u` before the xpath works. But, that is not a good solution.
The error seems to be on the python end.
Is there no way to add Japanese encoding to the script itself , so that it supports Japanese characters without decoding it to utf-8 as Umair told.

Answer (score 2):

Try to append to append string with `u`, like this

```
'Company_Name':response.xpath(u'//*[@id="anchor_realtorOutline"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/th[contains(text(), "会社名")]/following-sibling::td/p[1]/ruby/text()').extract(),
```

Comment: Thanks SAZ , that worked. But it's a bit annoying to encode each response to unicode.
And if possible can someone tell me, why it worked the first time and gave an error the second time.

Comment: Question what is change between first successful run and second run  :) You should consider to switch to Python 3, which use unicode for it's interpreter, to save your time encode \ decoding unicode

Comment: Nothing was changed. That is the strange part. i don't know if scrapy allows python 3. I'll take a look at that , if python 3 eliminates this problem and scrapy works on it too then it's better for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of why your xpath doesn't work is becuase of `tbody`. You have to remove it and check if you get that result that you want.

You can read this in scrapy documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/firefox.html

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding `<tbody>` elements to
>   tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page
>   HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use `<tbody>` in
>   your XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the response Umair, but i have already gone through the scrapy documentation for that, but it's not an issue here , because the website itself has the `<tbody>` tag.